# How to add new css class in @Html.TextBox mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used following code to add css class with `@Html.TextBox` but this is only working for `@Html.TextBoxFor` and not for `@Html.TextBox`.

```
@Html.TextBox("ticket_new_attachment_attributes_0_description", new { @class= "bigfield"})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBox("ticket_new_attachment_attributes_0_description", null, new { @class= "bigfield"})
```

Comment: This code does work, but note that Mario Sannum gives a reason as to why in his answer below. The second parameter is value, the third parameter is for attributes.

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter is the [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).
You need to use overload with the third parameter for html attributes, like so:

```
// Pass null (or the value) as second parameter
@Html.TextBox("ticket_new_attachment_attributes_0_description", null, new { @class = "bigfield"})
```

See the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505258%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For @Html.TextBox second parameter is textbox value 
so, you can pass "" as textbox value and third parameter is Html attributes

Try below html :

```
@Html.TextBox("ticket_new_attachment_attributes_0_description", "", new { @class= "bigfield"})
```

Comment: This question was asked 3y ago... And currently has best answer.